# can you have a heatsink on a raspberry pi 5 whilst also using the pcie m.2 hat?

Tags: hat, pi-5

The Raspberry Pi 5 has a PCIe 2.0 interface that requires a separate M.2 HAT to use with an M.2 drive, however, looking at pictures of the Raspberry Pi 5 with the hat I'm left to wonder...  will a heatsink even fit on the CPU if you're using the M.2 HAT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wondered the same thing!  Which is why I bought the opposite of a "HAT" (never liked that term) - [an NVME **base**](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/nvme-base?variant=41219587178579). I can say that this has worked well for me, and certainly no interference with the cooling gear (which is needed on the RPI 5).

[image]

Comment: I like it! Do you use that with a case? Every other raspberry pi I've had is in a case but I guess I don't really need that lol

Comment: @neubert: nah - cases are boring IMHO;  people notice the bare hardware, the cases are mostly UGLY and PLAIN. :)  If there is a case, I'd guess you'll need to get that from the same source as the NVME base.